# How to calculate the confidence interval for the difference between geometric means?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, geometric-mean

I am comparing the amount of leaf area eaten by herbivores between two groups of plants. This data is very zero-inflated (many leaves had no herbivory) with some very large values that skew the distribution - so, to derive a meaningful summary statistic I am using the geometric mean (adding 1 to each value to allow me to calculate a geometric mean from a variable which contains zeroes, then taking 1 from the final geometric mean). However, I also want to see what the difference in average leaf area lost is between the two groups - i.e. the geometric mean of one group minus the other.

How can I calculate a 95% confidence interval (or perhaps another measure to give context to the mean difference, like SE) for the difference between these two geometric means? Or in other words, how can I combine the two confidence intervals from the geometric mean of each population?

In my understanding, calculating a confidence interval for a mean difference should be done as follows:

[image]

Where X represents the mean, Z* the appropriate value from the standard normal distribution for the desired confidence level, σ the standard deviation and n the sample size.

Is it appropriate, when using geometric means, to just use the standard deviation of the log transformed variables and then back transform the final confidence interval value (i.e. take the exponential)?

I have found useful questions on how to calculate the confidence interval for geometric means, and on how to calculate the confidence interval for a difference between two means - but nothing on these two topics together?

See:
[How to calculate confidence interval for a geometric mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285173/how-to-calculate-confidence-interval-for-a-geometric-mean)

Comment: Why is geometric mean appropriate for zero-inflated data? The geometric mean of a sample with even a single zero is equal to zero.

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry good point - I am using the geometric mean for zero-inflated data with some very high values. In order to address to the presence of zeroes, I am adding 1 to each value and then taking 1 from the final geometric mean - which may not be appropriate? I have edited the question.

Comment: @WilliamBarker, that sounds about right way to deal with zeros in Geometric Mean calculation.